# How to pick some matching lines in text and append to a variable in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I found this discussion which is working off a command line output but not a variable. I have my text in a variable.

I am trying to find lines with the word `Melody` in them.

```
$output = 'This is some data
            Only the lines with Melody should be included
            For instance Mozart is a Melody
            But Justin Biber Beauty and the Beast is not
            Neither is anything Bieber ever did'

$skimmed = ''

$output | Where-Object { $_ -match '.*Melody.*' } | ForEach-Object {
                    $skimmed = $skimmed + $_ }
Write-Host $skimmed
```

The output it is writing is the following

```
            This is some data
            Only the lines with Melody should be included
            For instance Mozart is a Melody
            But Justin Biber Beauty and the Beast is not
            Neither is anything Bieber ever did
```

How can I pick only lines that are matching my pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the textblock in `$output` into separate lines first:

```
$output = 'This is some data
           Only the lines with Melody should be included
           For instance Mozart is a Melody
           But Justin Biber Beauty and the Beast is not
           Neither is anything Bieber ever did' -split '\r?\n'
```

`\r?\n` will match all newlines whether they are CRLF, LF or CR

P.S. I would change the remaining code to something like this:

```
$skimmed = $output | Where-Object { $_ -match 'Melody' } # or use $_ -like '*Melody*'

Write-Host (-join $skimmed)
```

Answer (score 1):

To *complement* [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65094323/45375), which solves your primary problem well:

Using the pipeline and cmdlets such as [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) is convenient, but *slow*.
**If *streaming* processing (one by one, in the pipeline) isn't *required*, you can simplify and speed up your filtering by using a PowerShell operator *directly* on the input**, given that comparison operators such as `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match), are capable of acting on ***arrays* as their LHS**, in which case they **act as *filters*** and return the *sub-array of matching elements*.

Therefore, your code can be rewritten as follows, which is both more concise and faster:

```
# Note the use of a here-string (@'<newline>...<newline>'@) 
$output = @'
This is some data
Only the lines with Melody should be included
For instance Mozart is a Melody
But Justin Biber Beauty and the Beast is not
Neither is anything Bieber ever did
'@ -split '\r?\n' 

# Since $output is an *array*, -match performs *filtering*.
$skimmed = $output -match 'Melody'
```

<sup>Note: If you really want to *concatenate* the matching lines to get a single-line string, use

`$skimmed = -join ($output -match 'Melody')` instead.</sup>

Note that `-match` by default matches *substrings* of the input strings, so it is sufficient to use just `'Melody'` as the regex rather than `'.*Melody.*'`.